# Liferay add custom permission

Tags: permissions, liferay, portlet, portal

I have a patient list portlet and a link in the portlet to "add a new patient" .

> Question : The link "add a new patient" should be displayed only for
>   users who are having a specific role.

I really appreciate if there are any example or links that could be shared or any ideas on how to achieve this in liferay portal.

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 2):

Get the role Ids of the user from themedisplay and compare with your role Id:

```
<%
    ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    long[] roleIds =  td.getUser().getRoleIds();

    boolean isRoleExist = false;
    for(Long roleid:roleIds){
        if(roleid == <your roleid here>){ // role id u can get it from liferay ROLE_ table inside db
            isRoleExist = true;
        }
    }
%>

<% if (isRoleExist){ %>
    <a href="#">add a new patient</a>
<%}%>
```

Comment: *Don't* hardcode roles or their ids into your UI or plugin. Rather use the concept of permissions (that are aggregated in any number of roles at runtime) and just check for an individual permission, like Pankaj Kathiriya states in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should create portlet-level permission for adding patient entry(e.g. ADD_PATIENT_ENTRY).
Then you can assign this permission to some Roles.

You can verify if current user has permission or not by code 
`PortletPermission.contains(permissionChecker, PAGELAYOUTID, PORTLETID, "ADD_PATIENT_ENTRY")`

Refer to [link](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions)

Comment: It didn't change a lot since 6.0, but here's the 6.2 version: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-06-en (weirder URL, but nicer formatting in the document)